# How to use awk '{print $1*Number}' from the second line or telling him to ignore NaN values?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, xargs

I have a file called 'waterproofposters.jsonl' with this type of output:

```
Regular price
100
200
300
400
500
```

And I need to take out 2% of each value. I have used the following code:

```
awk '{print $1*0.98}' waterproofposters.jsonl
```

And then I have the following output:

```
0
98
196
294
392
490
```

And then I'm stuck because I need to have 'Regular price' in the first line instead '0'

I thought to replace '0' with 'Regular price using

```
find . -name "waterproof.jsonl" | xargs sed -i -e 's/0/Regular price/g'
```

But it will replace all the '0' by 'Regular price'

Comment: You just need anchors, `sed -i 's/^0$/Regular price/'`

Comment: Yes, and it should be like that. If only the first line must be processed like this, `sed -i '1 s/^0$/Regular price/'` will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To print the first line as-is:

```
awk '{print (NR>1 ? $0*0.98 : $0)}'
```

To print lines that are not a number as-is:

```
awk '{print ($0+0 == $0 ? $0*0.98 : $0)}'
```

I'm using `$0` instead of `$1` in the multiplication because:

1. They're the same thing in your numerical input, and
2. I aesthetically prefer using the same value across the whole script rather than different values for the numeric vs non-numeric lines, and
3. When you use a specific field it causes awk to do field-splitting so it's a bit more efficient to not reference a field when the whole record will do.

Here's both of the above working with the posted sample input:

```
$ awk '{print (NR>1 ? $0*0.98 : $0)}' file
Regular price
98
196
294
392
490
```

```
$ awk '{print ($0+0 == $0 ? $0*0.98 : $0)}' file
Regular price
98
196
294
392
490
```

and here's the difference between the two given input that has a non-numeric value mid input file:

```
$ cat file
Regular price
100
200
foobar
400
500
```

```
$ awk '{print (NR>1 ? $0*0.98 : $0)}' file
Regular price
98
196
0
392
490
```

```
$ awk '{print ($0+0 == $0 ? $0*0.98 : $0)}' file
Regular price
98
196
foobar
392
490
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly achieve what you need [with a single `awk` call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68130842/3832970), but an answer to why your `sed -i -e 's/0/Regular price/g'` command did not work as expected is that you used `0` as the regex pattern. `0` matches any zero char inside the string.

You want to replace `0`s that are the only char on a line.

Hence, you need to use `^` and `$` anchors to match the start and end of the line respectively:

```sh
sed -i 's/^0$/Regular price/'
```

If you need to replace *on the first line only* add the `1` address before the `s`ubstitution command:

```sh
sed -i '1 s/^0$/Regular price/'
```

Note you do not need `g`, since you only expect one replacement per line and `g` is only needed when performing multiple replacements on a line. By default, all lines will get processed.

Answer (score 1):

*How to use awk '{print $1*Number}' from the second line or telling him to ignore NaN values?*

I would do it following way using GNU `AWK`, let `file.txt` content be

```
Regular price
100
200
300
400
500
```

then

```
awk 'NR==1{print}NR>=2{print $1*0.98}' file.txt
```

output

```
Regular price
98
196
294
392
490
```

Explanation: if it 1st line just print it, if it 2nd or later line print 0.98 of 1st column value

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*